# Как узнать имя вызывающего метода через рефлексию в Java

Tags: java, рефлексия

Нужно написать функцию, которая бы вернула полное имя класса и имя вызывающей функции в процессе выполнения. Полное имя класса я получаю, а как использовать получаемые с помощью .getDeclaredMethods() данные для определения имени вызывающего метода, не знаю.

```
// объект нужного класса
Class<?> c = new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
// полное имя класса
String nameFullleClass = c.getName();
// массив с именами всех методов
Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
```

**Вопрос:** как обработать массив, чтобы увидеть имя именно вызывающей функции? Или есть какой-то еще способ? Спасибо!

Comment: создайте эксцепшен, у него возьмите стек вызовов...

Answer (score 1):

Рефлексия для этого не предназначена. Это можно сделать с помощью `StackWalker`.

```java
System.out.println(StackWalker
        .getInstance()
        .walk(
                stackFrameStream -> stackFrameStream.map(
                        stackFrame -> stackFrame.getClassName() + " / " + stackFrame.getMethodName()
                ).skip(1).limit(1).collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).get(0));
```

Либо, как предложил `Stranger in the Q`, через `Exception`.

```java
StackTraceElement sTE = new Exception().getStackTrace()[1];

System.out.println(sTE.getClassName() + " / " + sTE.getMethodName());
```

Это, конечно, намного проще.

Comment: StackTraceElement можно без исключения получить - `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Решил с Thread.